# Replace the single quote (') character from a string

Tags: python, string

I need to strip the character `"'"` from a string in python. How do I do this?

I know there is a simple answer. Really what I am looking for is how to write `'` in my code. for example `\n` = newline.

Comment: Just for clarification: In python parlance, `strip` means `Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters removed`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip

Answer (score 110, accepted):

As for how to represent a single apostrophe as a string in Python, you can simply surround it with double quotes (`"'"`) or you can escape it inside single quotes (`'\''`).

To remove apostrophes from a string, a simple approach is to just replace the apostrophe character with an empty string:

```
>>> "didn't".replace("'", "")
'didnt'
```

Answer (score 19):

Here are a few ways of removing a single `'` from a string in python.

- [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

  `replace` is usually used to return a string with all the instances of the substring replaced.

  ```
  "A single ' char".replace("'","")
  ```
- `str.translate`

  [In Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

  To remove characters you can pass the first argument to the funstion with all the substrings to be removed as second.

  ```
  "A single ' char".translate(None,"'")
  ```

  [In Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

  You will have to use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)

  ```
  "A single ' char".translate(str.maketrans({"'":None}))
  ```
- [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.sub)

  Regular Expressions using `re` are even more powerful (but slow) and can be used to replace characters that match a particular regex rather than a substring.

  ```
  re.sub("'","","A single ' char")
  ```

Other Ways

There are a few other ways that can be used but are not at all recommended. (Just to learn new ways). Here we have the given string as a variable `string`.

- Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

  ```
  ''.join([c for c in string if c != "'"])
  ```
- Using [generator Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

  ```
  ''.join(c for c in string if c != "'")
  ```

Another final method can be used also (Again not recommended - works only if there is only one occurrence )

- Using [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#list) call along with [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

  ```
  x = list(string)
  x.remove("'")
  ''.join(x)
  ```

Comment: The `maketrans()/translate()` suggestion was great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
>>> mystring = "This isn't the right place to have \"'\" (single quotes)"
>>> mystring
'This isn\'t the right place to have "\'" (single quotes)'
>>> newstring = mystring.replace("'", "")
>>> newstring
'This isnt the right place to have "" (single quotes)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the apostrophe with a `\` character as well:

```
mystring.replace('\'', '')
```

Comment: I have sth like this: [{'connectEnd': 3001.174999997602, 'connectStart': 2878.519999998389, 'decodedBodySize': 48797, 'domComplete': 8718.204999997397, 'do... I'm trying to replace the apostrophes with double quotes like: content.replace('\'', '"') and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I met that problem in codewars, so I created temporary solution

```
pred = "aren't"
pred = pred.replace("'", "99o")
pred = pred.title()
pred = pred.replace("99O", "'")
print(pred)
```

You can use another char combination, like 123456k and etc., but the last char **should be letter**