# Replacing comma in Python

Tags: python

I am having a problem stripping commas out of a string while doing some web scraping. My code is as follows.

```
import urllib

import re

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen ("http://example.com") 

htmltext = htmlfile.read ()

regex = 'Posts: (.+?)\n'

value = re.compile(regex)

posts = re.findall(value,htmltext)

print posts[0]
```

Now I am getting the data ok but the problem is the post count is coming down with commas with a value such as 1,092,391, and I want to strip the commas out to leave a number such as 1092391.

I've got Python 2.7.1 installed and nothing I've found on here or Google has seemed to work. I am a bit of a newbie though, so I am no doubt missing something so silly here but I do love to learn and get my hands dirty. So any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Replace them:

```
posts[0].replace(',', '')
```

Or use the `locale` module (if your locale's thousands delimiter is a comma):

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
n = locale.atoi(posts[0])
```

I would advise against using just regex for scraping. Unless `Posts: (.*?)` is all you're after, parse the HTML with a HTML parser like lxml or BeautifulSoup.

Comment: The locale thing won’t work when you have for example a German locale where the comma is the decimal point separator (*“ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.092.391'”*).

Comment: @poke: Which is why I pointed it out in my comment.

Comment: That is my next step. I am very new to this. I intend to parse the HTML with my next step. Learning to code is easier than learning a spoken language I hope :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> '1,092,391'
'1,092,391'
>>> '1,092,391'.replace(',', '')
'1092391'
>>> int('1,092,391'.replace(',', ''))
1092391
```

---

> nothing I've found on here or Google has seemed to work

I’m having a hard time to believe that. A quick search for “Python string replace” should get you to [str.replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) very quickly, not to mention that searching it in the Python documentation gets you there even faster. The first result I get for “Python comma replace” is even [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354176/how-do-i-replace-commas-in-a-string) answering your problem.

And if everything failed, you could have used regular expressions which you apparently already know how to use.

Comment: Thank you for friendly reply. Apologies for any English problem. I have a .py file and not Python shell as this has to run on server. So I was having a hard time. I checked the link you gave me and I that came up with the Google search I mentioned. I got this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 14, in <module>
    price = price.replace(",", "")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

That is why it didn't work. Most things I try ends like this it seems. It is probably something really simple.

Comment: This seemed to work out ok for any future searches. 
print price[0].replace(',', '')

Answer (score 0):

here's a very simple way .. just replace the `,` with the empty string.

```
 >>> '1,092,391'.replace(',','')
 '1092391'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"".join('1,092,391'.split(','))
```