# Python: Efficient way to manipulate a string?

Tags: python, string

let's say you have the strings

```
    s1 = "('element1', 'element2', 'element3')"
```

and

```
    s2 = "(1A, 2A, 3A)"
```

Is there a simple technique you can use to convert

```
    s1 to "(element1, element2, element3)"
```

and

```
    s2 to "(1, 2, 3)"
```

For s1, every single-quotation mark needs to disappear, and for s2 each A should disappear. What's the most straightforward way to do this and only this?

**EDIT -> everything within quotation marks is part of the whole string... there are no tuples nor any variables. Thanks!**

Comment: Is `s1` supposed to be the string `"('element1', 'element2', 'element3')"`, or is it a tuple of three strings?

Comment: Sorry, yeah they're strings and not tuples! And there are no variables here in any of these examples..... they are literally just part of the string....

Comment: Your specification is incomplete. Please clarify what you're trying to do: what's the input and what's the expected output, preferrably with their types. Also, I'm not sure if you're looking for one universal method or different methods for `s1` and `s2`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stripping the single quote (') character from a Python string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151146/stripping-the-single-quote-character-from-a-python-string) ... works for `A` as well.

Comment: Which do you want, the most efficient way, or the most straightforward, as they're often not the same thing. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `s1` and `s2` are supposed to be the strings

```
s1 = "('element1', 'element2', 'element3')"
s2 = "(1A, 2A, 3A)"
```

To remove all single quotes from `s1`, you can use

```
s1 = s1.replace("'", "")
```

To remove all occurrences of the letter `A` from `s2`, use

```
s2 = s2.replace("A", "")
```

Note that strings can't be modified in place (they are immutable) -- `str.replace()` will return a new string.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see what all the confusion is, unforunately... but thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something?

```
>>> s1 = "('element1', 'element2', 'element3')"
>>> s2 = "(1A, 2A, 3A)"
>>> print s1.replace("'", "")
(element1, element2, element3)
>>> print s2.replace("A", "")
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to be doing these manipulations in string-land. What you really want is to parse your elements into a list of strings, manipulate them as a list, and join them back into a string.

You may find the following function useful. Of course, beware of security vulnerabilities if an attacker has control of the strings (and can for example insert `'` and `,` anywhere).

```
def tuplestringToList(s):
    """
        "(AAAAA, BBBBB , CCCCC)" -> ["AAAAA", "BBBBB", "CCCCC"]
    """
    assert s.startswith('(')
    assert s.endswith(')')
    return [fragment.strip() for fragment in s[1:-1].split(',')]

def listToTuplestring(myList):
    return '({})'.format(', '.join(myList))
```

Comment: "...elements into a of strings", shouldn't that read "...elements into a list of strings"?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s1 = "('element1', 'element2', 'element3')"
>>> result = ''.join([i for i in s1 if i != "'"])
>>> result
'(element1, element2, element3)'
>>> s2 = "(1A, 2A, 3A)"
>>> result = ''.join([i for i in s2 if i != "A"])
>>> result
'(1, 2, 3)'
```